# Solr filter query vs boolean query?

Tags: solr, lucene

For my implementation, i was previously using solr filter queries using solrj such as.

```
fq=content_source:SharePoint+AND+AuthenticatedUserName=lalit
```

But now as i am using lucene boolean query, query is built like this.

```
content_source=SharePoint&AuthenticatedUserName=lalit
```

I want to clarify what is difference between two options as i think boolean queries are also a kind of filter queries. Which one should be used in which scenarios.

Finally which one of these is more performant to use?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is {Filter}ing faster than {Query}ing in Lucene?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462350/is-filtering-faster-than-querying-in-lucene)

Comment: Thanks but after refering to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462350/is-filtering-faster-than-querying-in-lucene , my doubts are still unclear. I think filter queries are always faster because these run before main query and narrow down the result set at first place, that too without considering score. So it seems to be more performant always as for very large result sets, using a normal query will always add to time & resources.

Answer (score 0):

A Filter Query is used to figure out which documents belong in the result set and has no bearing on document-order within that result set.

The query will affect the order of the result within the result set.

If you search for example for `name:finn site:stackoverflow`, you'll get any documents with `name=finn` OR `site=stackoverflow` with those sharing both criteria sorted at the top. If instead you move the `site` to the Filter Query, you'll find that you *only* get results for `stackoverflow`, and within those, you'll only see the `finn`s.

To take it a little farther, if you search for `(name:finn OR name:chris) site:stackoverflow`, you'll get a large number of results with the `finn` and `chris` results floating to the top. If you again move the `site` to the Filter Query, you'll get only results with `site=stackoverflow` and only results with either `finn` or `chris`, and those with `finn` *and* `chris` will float to the top.